# Unknown column event_id in field list

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting the error:

> Unknown column event_id in field list

yet I have this column in both tables

```
SELECT 
event_id.events,
tournament.events, 
team1.events,
team2.events,event_date.events,
venue.events, picks.pick,tournament.picks
FROM  events 
INNER JOIN picks 
ON  `event_id`.events = `event_id`.picks
 WHERE tournament = 'SUPER15'
```

I have checked and tweaked and tried but I just can't figure out what is wrong...

TABLE EVENTS

[image]

TABLE PICKS

[image]

Comment: event_id is a column, not a table (I hope), so fix that first - likewise for ALL the other columns. Don't drink and sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First should be table name or alias than column name as below

```
 SELECT
    events.event_id,
    events.tournament, 
    events.team1, 
    events.team2,
    events.event_date,
    events.venue, 
    picks.pick,
    picks.tournament
FROM  events 
    INNER JOIN picks ON  
           events.`event_id` = picks.`event_id`
    WHERE 
        events.tournament = 'SUPER15'
```

You have to add column name for condition `WHERE tournament = 'SUPER15'` too. I changed it to `WHERE events.tournament = 'SUPER15'`. I also recommend you to use aliases as below

```
  SELECT 
       E.event_id,
       E.tournament, 
       E.team1, 
       E.team2,
       E.event_date,
       E.venue, 
       P.pick,
       P.tournament
 FROM  events E
    INNER JOIN picks P ON  
              E.`event_id` = P.`event_id`
    WHERE 
        E.tournament = 'SUPER15'
```

It's more readable, isn't?

Comment: Thank you, im getting an empty result back any idea why since in WHERE clause there are multiple entries of that tournament name

Comment: Never mind ive got error thank you will accept when time expires

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee I updated my answer there is info about it :)

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying your selections in reverse order. It should be `table.column`:

```
SELECT events.event_id,events.tournament, events.team, events.team2,
       events.event_date, events.venue, pick.picks,picks.tournament
FROM  events 
INNER JOIN picks ON  `event_id`.events = `event_id`.picks
WHERE tournament = 'SUPER15'
```